# Excel calculation problems

Tags: c#, .net, excel-2007, openxml

I have .xlsx document in which I need to import some values to cells with defined names. Few of those cells are formatted as currency and values that I am importing in those cells are of `decimal` type which I import in this manner:

```
cell.CellValue = new CellValue(value.ToString().Replace(",", "."));
```

In the same spreadsheet there are a few cells that have a formula in which currency cells I imported are used (eg., I am importing value in cell `H27` with defined name `Total`, and in the field `I27` there is a formula `=Total*0.23`).

After import is complete, values are successfully imported (and correctly formatted as currency), but formula cells are not correctly calculated until I either click on formula check marks for each formula cell or I change the currency value (in this case, all formulas containing this cell are refreshed).

What do I have to do for cells with formulas to automatically calculate values after import is completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out. The cells with formula have `<CellFormula>` fields inside of them. Those fields have `bool` attribute `CalculateCell` which, if set to true, tells Excel to calculate the formula after opening the file. Since I don't know up front which formula cells are affected by the cells, I manage all of them like this:

```
   foreach (var cell in sheetData.Descendants<CellFormula>())
      cell.CalculateCell = true;
```